# Fading text+icon when scrolling down. Appears while again on top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to create some sort of info "Scroll Down" button (not clickable) which has to be visible while scroll bar is up on top, fade out when scroll down a few pixels and fade back in when up again.

So far I was able to create the arrow and the message so far as well as the fading part.

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8b3jL7r0/1/

```
var btn = $("#button");

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() < 100) {
    btn.addClass("show");
  } else {
    btn.removeClass("show");
  }
});

var btn2 = $("#scrolltxt");

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() < 100) {
    btn2.addClass("showx");
  } else {
    btn2.removeClass("showx");
  }
});
```

1. The problem with is that the arrow and the info text 'Scroll Down' does not appear right from the beginning, you have to scroll down a bit so they appear on top and then everything works smooth. Any clue how to make them visible right from the first load of the code?
2. Any idea how could I transfer all this code into one single code module in WordPress and have it work exactly like in the fiddle ? Because I've tried to insert it but it seems to not work at all, nothing appears on the page, not the arrow nor the info text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added the inital classes to both elements:

https://jsfiddle.net/4e2cafju/

```
<div id="button" class="show"></div>
<div id="scrolltxt" class="showx">scroll down</div>
```

for 2:

You should be able to put these elements directly into a template.  You should be able to add the css to the style sheet.  And you could lnk to an external JS file.  That would probably be best practice.  You could also put all the code into a single page.  I'm not sure how your wordpress install / theme is set up.

Comment: Of course that was missing, because I'm a rookie, I make rookie mistakes. Thanks a lot

Comment: @labilouser Not a biggie.  It happens.

Comment: later edit:  so managed to insert it in WordPress as well, loaded jQ library in html an works like a charm. thanks again

Comment: @labilouser No problem. Can you mark it as answered or add your own answer in case someone stumbles across this in the future?